# Ohai fails to determine os_version in cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, chef-infra

I'm trying to run `ohai.bat os_version` within cygwin on Windows Server 2003 R2, and it returns an empty array as output. If I instead run `ohai os_version` in cmd.exe, then it correctly returns:

```
[
   "5.2.3790"
]
```

Given that `ohai.bat os_version` works on another one of my virtual machines, I'm inclined to believe that this is an environment misconfiguration of some form. Does anyone have any ideas on what to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is caused by `systemu` not properly quoting directory names. This [commit](https://github.com/ahoward/systemu/commit/613df510c492759a7fd390f98223dfe73b16a820#comments) fixes the problem, but is not currently available in any released gem. It will be in version 2.0.0 of `systemu`. To fix it in your own project for now, you'll need to clone `systemu` off github and build the gem yourself.